# Steps of Creating new Screen in android

Tags: android

What's the steps of creating & Open new Screen in Android.

I am using Eclipse IDE

What i mean by new screen is when i click on button it will take me to next screen(layout)

Comment: start with http://developer.android.com

Comment: very much depends what IDE you are using. You should try to ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it obvious to look up for Google guideline before asking here?
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 7):

I assume you mean Activities by "new screens". Well:

1. With the new ADT v. 20 it is very easy. Right-click on your project and then click on new -> other:
   [image]
2. Click on Android Activity:
   [image]
3. Now Name your Class
4. Start the Activity from your first Activity (from a Button etc.) like this:

   `Intent i = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);`

Comment: do i have to take a new class for new layout(new screen)

Comment: This will automatically create a new class, a new layout and will write down the Activity in the Android Manifest

Comment: this is great...much more concise and to the point compared to the google documentation